# Save Data in Backendless after saving in realm database

Tags: android, realm, backendless

I am new to use Backendless as well as realm database.When i create profile in my application i saved that data in realm as well as backendless it work fine.
I have RealmList in my model class.When i want to update that profile at that time it successfully updated in realm database but when try to save that in backendless i am getting error [image]like:

Comment: Please share the schema of your tables (from Backendless console)

Comment: Realm must be substituting the object stored in the "phoneNumberRelation" property with a proxy it creates.

Comment: I am getting solution for this issue. thanx